# Decoding multiline string in JSON file using json_decode()

Tags: php, json

I'm new to JSON so having some trouble parsing it.

I made a JSON file:

> newjson.json
>
> ```
> {
>     "title":"My Title",
>     "contents":"My\
>                 Multiline\
>                 Contents"
> }
> ```

I used `\` to avoid an error in JavaScript syntax that doesn't allow multiline strings, but when I load it with `file_get_contents()` and decode it using `json_decode()` in PHP, it can't parse it.

I think I should handle the `\`s with `preg_replace`, or something before I put the string in a decode function.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP can't parse your string because [it's not valid JSON](http://www.json.org/). The only valid escape sequences are:

- `\"` for a quotation mark
- `\\` for a backslash
- `\/` for a forward slash
- `\b` for a backspace
- `\f` for a formfeed
- `\n` for a newline
- `\r` for a carriage return
- `\t` for a tab
- `\uxxxx` for a hexadecimal escape

Use a newline escape instead if you want literal newlines. Otherwise, you'll have to live with a less-pretty string.

```
{
    "title":"My Title",
    "contents":"My\nMultiline\nContents"
}
```

Comment: Oh, I just wanted to seperate long string contents for readability when writing it. Then isn't that possible? should I have to let it in one line?

Comment: @Young-HoKim: Yes, it will have to be in one line.

Answer (score 1):

there must be something wrong in your in json syntax that's why it can't parse it...

try your http://json.parser.online.fr/

copy your whole json string there and try to manipulate that...you may find your error there